# Flutter web app fails to get node API on the same pc

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, flutter-web

I have created a flutter web app which uses NodeJS API to fetch data from mongodb database and write some data to mongodb. The app works fine when i run it as a Desktop app,it communicates to my node server. The app also work fine when i run it on chrome using

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

from android studio terminal. But when i build the web app and run it with the bellow command only the static page loads and it is not fetching data from mongoDB. It isnot communicating with NodeJS API.

```
flutter build web
cd build/web
python -m http.server 8000
```

So all i want was to deploy my flutter web app to a server and check if it works properly, but it fails to connect to the NodeJS back end. What is the best way to do it,Deploy a Flutter web app with also uses NodeJS APIs to fetch some JSON data.

Comment: What do you see in the console in Chrome?

Comment: There are many errors on chrome terminal.  These are some, Service worker not supported (or configured). Falling back to plain <script> tag. Object
_loadWithServiceWorker @ flutter.js:93     Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9636/fetchSimAdvisoryNotice/B787%20FFS' from origin 'http://0.0.0.0:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.

Comment: Enable CORS on your API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#the_http_response_headers.

Comment: I'm using a node js server and i have installed the CORS module and set it up as it was in the guide but it is the same. Sorry but i did not get how to implement you suggestion as per the above link. I do not know how to implement it on a node js and express server

Answer (score 0):

Enable CORS for API. Here is an example which enables it for all requests.

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

...

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

See [cors](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) for details.

Comment: This does not work, I have tried it. It's the same